Can anyone identify this window shade part?
Photos
I was shortening my cordless faux wood Allen + Roth window blinds from Lowe’s when the lift strings retracted into the clutch/cord lock mechanism at the top. I removed the part but I’m not sure how to restring it and I can’t find it anywhere online.
The sticker on top says “2B64-1” and the brass-colored part says “220606D” with “0.12*1860” underneath it.
Does anyone know how to restring this or find it online for a reference?
Photos

Do you have another set of blinds you can look at?
